# Iterate over ContextMenuStrip items in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, contextmenustrip

I would like to iterate over all items in a ContextMenuStrip.

Can somebody please help me out here?

I was trying this, but it didn't work out:

```
For Each it As ToolStripItem In Me.ContextMenuStrip1.Items
```

Thank you!

Comment: that looks correct to me, what does the error say?

Comment: LOL, sorry! The error says "Add a 'Next'" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear to me =).  Add the word `Next` where your loop ends.

```
For Each it As ToolStripItem In Me.ContextMenuStrip1.Items
    'Loop Contents
Next
```